# Allowing a method to take only numbers?

Tags: c#, methods, numbers

*Updated:* How could I make a method with **two** paramerters to take any primitive number type, like `int`, `uint`, `float`, `double`, etc, (except `bool`)?

I'm currently using an `object`, but that means the method can accept any type.

```
public int[] MyNumberMethod(object a, object b)
{
    if (a is int || a is uint || a is short || a is ushort || a is long || a is ulong || a is byte || a is sbyte || a is float || a is double || a is decimal)
    {
        if (b is int || b is uint || b is short || b is ushort || b is long || b is ulong || b is byte || b is sbyte || b is float || b is double || b is decimal)
            return new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(b), Convert.ToInt32(a) };
    }

    return new int[] { 0, 0 };
}
```

Comment: use method overloading

Comment: I don't think this is possible _(**EDIT:** Apart from when performing method overloading)_. What I would do is to create a custom structure able of holding only those types (requires checking though, as you do above).

Comment: My suggestion is not very good though compared to what the others have given you. ;)

Comment: @VisualVincent Don't be down on yourself. Anything is fine as long as it works. :)

Comment: Right then, but you'll have to wait until I'll be able to both write and test the code (that is, sometime tomorrow night) because this is one of the few things I won't be able to write directly from the top of my head.

Comment: @VisualVincent All good. :)

Comment: Well then, now you have yet another option!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be as good as the other answers, but another option is to create your own structure where you only allow a value of certain data types:

```
public struct Number
{
    #region Static methods and fields
        private static readonly Type[] allowedTypes = new Type[] { 
            typeof(int), typeof(uint), typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
            typeof(long), typeof(ulong), typeof(byte), typeof(sbyte),
            typeof(float), typeof(double), typeof(decimal)
        };

        private static void CheckIsNumber(dynamic val) {
            if (Array.IndexOf(allowedTypes, val.GetType()) == -1) { throw new InvalidCastException("Input type must be a number."); }
        }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
        public Number(dynamic Value) {
            Number.CheckIsNumber(Value);
            _value = Value;
        }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
        private dynamic _value;
        public dynamic Value {
            get { return _value; }
            set {
                Number.CheckIsNumber(value);
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    #endregion

    #region Overridden methods
        public override bool Equals(object obj) { return _value.Equals(obj); }
        public override int GetHashCode()       { return _value.GetHashCode(); }
        public override string ToString()       { return _value.ToString(); }
    #endregion

    #region Conversion operators - Number
        public static implicit operator Number(uint val)    { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(short val)   { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(ushort val)  { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(long val)    { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(ulong val)   { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(byte val)    { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(float val)   { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(double val)  { return new Number(val); }
        public static implicit operator Number(decimal val) { return new Number(val); }
    #endregion

    #region Conversion operators - Misc. data types
        public static implicit operator int(Number num)     { return (int)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator uint(Number num)    { return (uint)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator short(Number num)   { return (short)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator ushort(Number num)  { return (ushort)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator long(Number num)    { return (long)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator ulong(Number num)   { return (ulong)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator byte(Number num)    { return (byte)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator sbyte(Number num)   { return (sbyte)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator float(Number num)   { return (float)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator double(Number num)  { return (double)num.Value; }
        public static implicit operator decimal(Number num) { return (decimal)num.Value; }
    #endregion
}
```

Every time you change the value or create a new instance of the structure it will verify if the input value's data type matches any of the items in the `allowedTypes` array. If not it will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

I have also added conversion operators which will let you use this as a normal number, thus you can use it pretty much like you would use any other numerical data type:

```
Number myNum = 3.5;
myNum += 10.4;
double something = myNum - 6.0;
```

However keep in mind that you must add a decimal point when working with `double`, `float`, etc. or else it will assume that the number is an integer:

```
Number myNum = 3.5;
myNum -= 2;
MessageBox.Show(myNum.ToString()); //Shows "1" as the second line converts 'myNum' into an integer.
```

---

All that said, here's how you would use it for your method:

```
public int[] MyNumberMethod(Number a, Number b)
{
    try {
        return new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(b), Convert.ToInt32(a) };
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException) {
        return new int[] { 0, 0 };
    }
}
```

And thanks to the conversion operators you won't need to specify a `(Number)` conversion. For example:

```
byte myByte = 133;

//Unnecessary.
MyNumberMethod((Number)17.4, (Number)myByte);

//This works just as fine.
MyNumberMethod(17.4, myByte);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with this +1. It seems like the most simple option. ;)

Comment: @shad0wk : Thanks! I wouldn't agree with it being the most simple option, but from now on you will certainly not need to write as much code in your methods (that is, if you are going to use this in more than one method) as the structure does all checking you require for you.

Comment: "write less code in your methods", that what I meant by simple. It works great.

Answer (score 3):

Well since you want to use all primitive types except the bool, how about that?

```
public int MyNumberMethod<T>(T number) where T : struct
{
    if (!(number is bool) && number.GetType().IsPrimitive) 
        return Convert.ToInt32(number);

    return 0;
}
```

e.g.

```
MyNumberMethod<short>(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

All numeric types (except double and float) are implicitly convertible to decimal and float is implicitly convertible to double. So if you make overloads like:

```
Method(double, double)
Method(decimal, double)
Method(decimal,decimal)
Method(double, decimal)
```

Your method will be callable with any two numbers but only with any two numbers.

Comment: @shad0wk Or define a struct that will handle all wanted implicit conversions (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/85w54y0a.aspx ) and use it as argument type

Answer (score 0):

First you must call other function like GenericNumberMethod, that will contain the calling to MyNumberMethod. You must have for each data type an implementacion of GenericNumberMethod with the corresponding parameter

```
public int MyNumberMethod(object number) {
    return Convert.ToInt32(number);
}

public int GenericNumberMethod(int number) {
    return MyNumberMethod(number);
}

public int GenericNumberMethod(decimal number) {
    return MyNumberMethod(number);
}
```